# dynamo insert or update based on condition boto3

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-dynamodb, boto3, dynamodb-queries

I have a dynamo table structure as:

```
partKey     sortKey         thirdAttribute
1           sort1               x
2           sort2               y
1           sort2               w
2           sort3               z
```

here is how I want to insert or update:

insert if combination of partition+sortKey does not exist

update only if:

combination of partition+sortKey exist but thirdAttribute=x or y if the new item is as follow:

```
item:{
    "partKey":1,
    "sortKey":"sort1",
    "thirdAttribute":"k"
}
```

or

```
item:{
    "partKey":2,
    "sortKey":"sort2",
    "thirdAttribute":"l"
}
```

and the new table should look like:

```
partKey     sortKey         thirdAttribute
1           sort1               k(updated)
2           sort2               l(updated)
1           sort2               w
2           sort3               z
2           sort4               k (inserted)
```

tried with below but does not work per expectation:

```
table.put_item(
        Item=item,
        ConditionExpression='partKey <> :v_partKey AND sortKey <>:v_sortKey and (attribute_not_exists(thirdAttribute) '
                            'or thirdAttribute <> :v_thirdAttribute_x or thirdAttribute <> :v_thirdAttribute_y)',
    ExpressionAttributeValues={':v_partKey': item['partKey'], ':v_apId': item['sortKey'], ':v_thirdAttribute_x': 'x',':v_thirdAttribute_y':'y'}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
table.put_item(
        Item=json_data,
        ConditionExpression='(attribute_not_exists(partKey) and attribute_not_exists(sortKey)) or (thirdAttribute <> :v_thirdAttribute_x or thirdAttribute <> :v_thirdAttribute_y)',
    ExpressionAttributeValues={':v_thirdAttribute_x': 'x',
                               ':v_thirdAttribute_y': 'y'}
    )
```